# How to calculate the overhead of wrapping multiple elementary streams?

Tags: ffmpeg

I run a web service which muxes multiple elementary streams (e.g., H.264 + FLAC) into a single matroska container/wrapper/file. There is no transcoding as I only copy the streams, using a process like `ffmpeg  -i i.mkv -i i.flac   -map 0:0 -c:0 copy -map 1:0 -c:1 copy out.mkv`.

The problem is that the service must provide the total file size (in bytes) of the file (`out.mkv`) resulting from the mux up front (i.e., before the actual muxing completes).  Is it possible to calculate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since different containers have a different overhead over actual data. But you can predict size, if you calculate average difference of source and destination files on actual files.

Other way - calculate size, using actual data, but it may be very slow, as you must walk throw all your data and calculate every chunk size. For this, you can use tool `ffprobe` to get size of every frame or chunk.

Answer (score 2):

The only exact approach is to simulate the muxing. On a *nix system this would be

```
ffmpeg -i i.mkv -i i.flac -c copy -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -f matroska /dev/null
```

At the bottom of console readout, there's this line:

```
frame=152217 fps=71723 q=-1.0 Lsize=  551301kB time=01:41:28.66 ...
```

The `Lsize` is what you want. This operation is pretty quick as there's nothing written to disk.